# How to remove points from line chart in ReCharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

I want to render just the line without the points. I'm using: http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/LineChart

[image]

Here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gw7v4br8/87/

```
const {LineChart, Line} = Recharts;
const data = [
      {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
      {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
      {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
      {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
      {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
      {name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500},
      {name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100},
];
const TinyLineChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <LineChart width={300} height={100} data={data}>
        <Line type='monotone' dataKey='pv' stroke='#8884d8' strokeWidth={1} />
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <TinyLineChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

In their API for line chart I don't see a point API, would this even be possible with this library?

http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/LineChart

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're after, but it might be relevant to check out libraries like [react-trend](https://github.com/unsplash/react-trend) or [react-sparklines](https://github.com/borisyankov/react-sparklines).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to add a prop to the `<Line>` components you are rendering in order to hide the "dots".

The props to add is the `dot` prop and you should provide it the value `false` in order to hide the dots.

So the line where you render the `<Line>` components should become:

```
<Line type='monotone' dataKey='pv' stroke='#8884d8' strokeWidth={1} dot={false} />
```

Comment: They still appear on hover :)

Comment: @trainoasis try activeDot={false}